# Image Resize Issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an img tag

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCatalog" ImageAlign="middle"    Height='<%#GetImageWidth(Eval("PictureName")) %>' ImageUrl='<%#GetImageUrl(Eval("PictureName")) %>'   runat="server"/>
```

i want to resize every image during loading the page and i used GetImageWidth function.

```
public Unit GetImageWidth(object ImageName)
{
    string strimagename = Convert.ToString(ImageName);
    //string strimagewidth = "";
    int width = 0;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(GetImageUrl(strimagename))))
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(GetImageUrl(strimagename)));
        if (img.Height > 1000)
        {
            //strimagewidth = "535px";
            **width = 535;**
            ------------
        }
        else
        {
            //strimagewidth = img.Width.ToString() + "px";
            width = img.Width;
        }
        img.Dispose();
    }

    return Unit.Pixel(width);
}
```

I want to set image height not image width.but i didnt get height property inside the function.Can any body help

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Here you can specify both the height and width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

For the Height Property value, you are calling the GetImageWidth function which is currently returning the width. Do you have a similar method which returns the Height ? some thing which returns the Height of Image based on your custom conditions ? Some thing like this ?

```
public Unit GetImageHeight(string ImageName)
{
    int height= 0;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(GetImageUrl(ImageName))
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(GetImageUrl(ImageName)));
        if (img.Width > 1000)                      
           height = 535;        
        else
            height= img.height;

        img.Dispose();
    }
    return Unit.Pixel(height);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have to do that you set the `Height`, but you call the `width`.

```
Height=getWidth()
```